# Parse a RSS Feed to csv

Tags: python, python-requests, rss

I'm trying to parse a google trends Rss feed to a csv.

```
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__));
os.chdir(dir_path)

z=requests.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=US')


from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse((z.text))
root = tree.getroot()

for att in root:
    first = att.find('title').text
    for subatt in att.find('ht:news_item_title'):
        second = subatt.find('ht:approx_traffic').text
        print('{},{}'.format(first, second))
```

I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole XML contents as the filename, which is why you're getting the error.

Change it to `fromstring` [as per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) since you're reading an rss file.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
root = ElementTree.fromstring(z.text)
```

You'll have to rewrite the logic for finding the elements you want after that.

Comment: I am having issues with the logic for finding elements.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? There is not enough information in your question and I have already fixed your error.

Comment: My aplologies, I am trying to get data from the RSS feed and save it as a csv. I am actually stuck at parsing the xml document because i could not get the elements inside the tags with my code.